# Gods are dogs, but why?

Tags: society, culture, fauna, religion, gods

It’s obvious, really: “God” and “dog” are just two sides of the same coin. Literally any pantheon, deity, or divine force that’s ever existed - yep, they’re all dogs somewhere.

But why? What reason could the omnipotent creator of the universe have to take on the form of man’s best friend?

Vaguely plausible answers preferable. If you’re a being capable of literally anything conceivable, would you really want to be a dog?

(Huge thanks to @Tim B for [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32086/santa-is-satan-but-why).)

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that real-life deities are all dogs, or that all the deities In your world are dogs?

Comment: [We help building worlds, not stories](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se?noredirect=1)  Asking us to justify an idea this broad makes this a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions) which is off-topic until narrowed to fit SE's one-specific-question/one-best-answer scope.

Comment: In regards to the link to the "Santa is Satan, but why?" question, the Santa series of questions are a tradition on WB.SE that intentionally break the rules.  They are not acceptable references for on-topic-ness.

Comment: This question was closed as primarily opinion-based, but I'd like to note that there were two folks who voted to close this as off-topic - so its opinionated nature isn't the only problem here, as @JBH mentioned.

Comment: The linked santa question was a bad fit for the site but people decided to keep it.

Comment: Fair points. I have a tendency towards opinion-based questions partly to help gather perspectives I wouldn’t normally consider, but I didn’t realise the Santa/Satan question had been judged as too far. Will adjust in future. :)

Answer (score 5):

A funny thing about being a deity is that it's not always obvious who is the head honcho.  You can appear to have omipotent power to those little cute humans scurrying about, while still having to defer to the commander and chief.

So we humans see a bunch of deities that are all dogs.  Funny.  I wonder why all deities are dogs?  I might even ask the question on Stack Exchange.  But I have to see through.  I have to see through to that clever conniving mastermind who lets all the dogs do their dirty work for them.

Yes.  The real deity is a cat.  The real deity is any cat, and all cats.

Specifically, [these cats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0DrQ78CQaE).

Comment: Most of the humans in that video sound like they're speaking Russian.  Mother Russia breeds cats with fortitude...  *Da!*

Answer (score 4):

The "creator" is dyslexic.  As such: "god" and "dog" are identical.

Also, (s)he can judge how Man treats his "best friend".  This helps approve/deny Satan's request for an expansion.

Comment: And the agnostic dyslexic insomniac lies awake all night wondering if there really is a dog.

Comment: @manassehkatz Dog forbid!